# Command line photo printing in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, printing, photo

I need to print a photo (.jpg) from the command line in Windows 7. I have tried using lpr to no success, and found methods for Windows XP like the following:

```
rundll32 shimgvw.dll ImageView_PrintTo /pt myPhoto.jpg "myPrinter"
```

This doesn't work (not surprising), and my hours of Googling has turned up nothing else. I'm trying to find a stock way to do this on any Windows 7 machine without needing to install or set anything up. Does there exist such a command?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe reformatting the command and adding some absolute paths would help? The following worked for me:

```
rundll32 C:\WINDOWS\system32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_PrintTo "c:\mydir\my.bmp" "Fictional HP Printer"
```

Comment: Verifying this works on Windows7.  The OP is missing a comma.

Comment: it also works without the comma (tested on windows 10). It needs to have absolute paths

Answer (score 5):

Try via MS Paint

```
mspaint /pt <FILE> <PRINTER>
```

Works like a charme for me.

Comment: Works on both Windows 7 and Windows 8.

Comment: Is there a way to get this to print in portrait orientation?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look here?

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/87e942da-faec-48e1-b339-7ba3da7c9134

The provided rundll32 command line looks slightly different from yours.  Alternatively, the page implies that mspaint.exe has a command-line option to print.

Note that I haven't tried any of these, though...