# Print an image in Matlab GUI

Tags: image, matlab, printing

How do you print an image from a printer in Matlab GUI? I get an error using the code below. Please help me.

```
smapleimage = imread('image.png');
printdlg(handles.smapleimage)
```

...

```
Undefined function or variable 'smapleimage'.
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because smapleimage is numeric, while printdlg only accepts figure handles.

**1)**
One may either create a matlab figure first (it might be hidden though)

```
smapleimage = imread('image.png');
image(smapleimage)
printdlg
```

**2)**
..or call some system tool, to print from command line, like this:

```
system('mspaint /pt image.png');
```

Other command-line printing options are discussed here: [1](https://superuser.com/questions/477895/printing-from-windows-7-command-line),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321919/command-line-photo-printing-in-windows-7),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301101/command-line-tool-for-print-picture) .